# Rate Limiting by NGINX within one connection

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to implement a rate limiting mechanism that could help me reduce the number of requests during the same connection to reduce abuse of some flaws in the backend.

I've already tried the limit_rate_zone, but I couldn't figure out which key I should use to address my task. I know that NGINX counts requests that arrived within the same connection - for this purpose there is a $connection_requests, but I haven't come up with any ideas yet.
I would be really cool if you share your experience or if you could point me in the right direction to carry out this task.